# Input form where user could enter regular expression

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, input

I have a rails application in which I need to create some input form where user could enter regular expression. This regex needed to be passed to my method check_site(url, regex) that will return true or false depends on regex found on the page.
I've tried to create a 'link_to':

```
link_to 'Search', check(item.name, @pattern)
```

In this case method "check" is called not with button pressed but with page loading.
Do I need to use JS+AJAX? How to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crash course on getting AJAX/JS set up with your Rails form:

1. Ensure correct javascript is called in your page `<head>`: JQuery + application.js (Jquery-compatible version, of course!)
2. Change your link to:

   ```
   link_to 'Search', check_item_path(:name=>item.name, :id=>@pattern, :var=>var, etc.), :remote => true
   ```
3. In items_controller:

   ```
   def check  
     ...your regex...  
     respond_to do |format|  
       format.html { redirect_to ...(wherever you'd like if no .js) }  
       format.js  
     end  
   end
   ```
4. Create a file called `check.js.erb` in the corresponding views folder and enter the javascript you'd like to update the page / confirm the form's successful submission / return results from your search, etc.

   ```
   $(document).ready( function() {
     $("#result").html(" <%= @item.result == true ? "true" : "false" %> ");
   });
   ```

#### No method error: check_item_path

This means Rails is not recognizing the route to that controller action. Run `rake routes` in console and see if anything corresponds to the items controller, check_item action. If not, add:

```
match 'items/check_item'
```

to your routes file. Then run rake routes again and you should see `check_item` appear somewhere - if it does, you can use `check_item_path` again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll give it a try. Will report soon

Comment: @sscirrus I'm getting "No method error: check_item_path". Here is more info about my app: http://pastebin.com/23UW8Xct. I'm completely confused

Comment: @name - no problem, you just need to set up your routes properly. I'll edit my answer above.

Comment: Ok I've done with routing. Now I'm getting error from search.js.erb: undefined method `result'

Comment: Oh I understand what to do next. Thanks